# Position child absolutely without a height on the parent

Tags: html, css, position, height

I have an absolutely positioned div inside a  without a height.

I need to ensure the child "fills" the available height space inside the parent i.e. the  will have a red background if this is working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/richardblyth/AvSr9/

(This is an adaptation of a requirement for a client project I'm working on...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">     
        <title>A Blank HTML Doc</title>

       <style type="text/css">
        section {
            position: relative;
            width: 600px;
        }
        div.content {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
            background: red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
           <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vehicula urna sit amet nibh facilisis, vitae feugiat felis imperdiet. Nunc facilisis ac tortor at rutrum. Fusce ligula sem, vehicula a sapien in, iaculis faucibus nulla. Nam faucibus feugiat ante, et ornare turpis aliquam vel. Donec non semper velit. Pellentesque vehicula enim lacinia, sagittis neque et, lobortis sapien. Quisque bibendum elementum nunc. Phasellus ac tincidunt tellus.</div>
        </section>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do not specify height attribute for div.content and it will work

Comment: Yeah, don't give it height: 100%; as that is getting 100% of nothing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AvSr9/6/

Comment: I think the masonry script I have running (on the production version) is causing problems. Time for a rethink! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify height for the `section` element. So `section` element has `height: 0`.

So in the `div.content` `height: 100%` will lead to `height: 0`.

Just dont include height attribute in `div.content` CSS.

Try:

```
div.content {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AvSr9/7/)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna 100% of parent's height, all that you need is :

```
div.content {
width:100%; /* or left:0; right:0; */
top: 0;
bottom: 0; /* same as height:100% */
position: absolute;
background: red;
```

}

But if your section haven't any height you can try this technique :

```
section {
    display:table;
    width: 600px;
}
div.content {
    display:table-cell;
    background: red;
}
```